# Is there a way to use filewriter in java to open different text files

Tags: java, netbeans

I want to basically code the `filewriter` in such a way so that I can call the same method for writing of data into different text files. 
For example, if I have an admin, manager and supplier, I want to call same method for all of them but have different text files.

p.s // Sorry for my confusing question, it's just that I'm having a lot of difficulty understanding this language and our lecturer is no help to me at all.

```
package catalogue;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class UserDetails {
public String userID;

public String name, address,emailID,role,username,password;

public void write(String id,String name,String add,String email,String role,String un,String pass)
{
    this.userID = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.address = add;
    this.emailID = email;
    this.role = role;
    this.username = un;
    this.password = pass;
FileWriter fw;       
try{
 fw =  new FileWriter("userdetails.txt",true);
 fw.write(un+"|");
 fw.write(pass+"|");     
 fw.write(id+"|");
 fw.write(name+"|" ); 
 fw.write(email+"|");
 fw.write(role+"|");
 fw.write(add+"|");
 fw.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
 fw.close();
} 
     catch (IOException ex) 
    {
        Logger.getLogger(UserDetails.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is given as String to the `FileWriter`; in your example "userdetails.txt".
If you want to write to a different file you just need to change that String.
You could add the name of the file to your `write()` method i.e.

```
public void write(String fileName,String id,String name,String add,String email,String role,String un,String pass)
{
    ...
    FileWriter fw;       
    try{
        fw =  new FileWriter(fileName,true);
        ...
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) 
    {
        Logger.getLogger(UserDetails.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```